# CodeNameOne Google Plus OAuth2

Tags: codenameone

Could anyone please help me with authenticating to Google Plus using OAuth2? I am able to get the authentication window to display, login and confirm my application with my account, but for some reason the action event is never fired. I get a screen saying Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there.

How do i get the action event to fire?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My code is as follows:

Hi Shai, thanks for the response, my code for the authentication is as follows:

```
Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "Client_Id", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob or http://localhost", "openid", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "Client_Secret");


Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);
auth2.showAuthentication(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof String) {
            String token = (String) evt.getSource();
            String expires = Oauth2.getExpires();
            GOOGLE_TOKEN = token;
            System.out.println("recived a token " + token + " which expires on " + expires);
            //store token for future queries.
        } else {
            Exception err = (Exception) evt.getSource();
            err.printStackTrace();
            Dialog.show("Error", "An error occurred while logging in: " + err, "OK", null);
        }
    }
});
```

The "auth2.showAuthentication" works well, and allows you to pass through for the user to authorize the application but then once the user authorizes the application the "actionlistener" is never called, I never hit the callback. How can i force the callback to fire to return the token?

Comment: Its unclear to me what exactly you are trying to do and how you implemented that. If you supply some additional information as to how you used Codename One and I assume the OAuth2 API we might be able to help you.

Comment: Will follow up with code now

Comment: Is this: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob or http://localhost the actual string that you used?
What did you define when you signed up for the developer key? You need to use that URL since the redirect google sends should send you to that location

Comment: I can use both, the "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" displays the auth token on a webpage once completed, but the "localhost" is supposed to return and execute the callback method as far as I understand.

Comment: You should use one or the other. The way this works is that OAuth2 after it finishes sends a redirect to that given page and we compare the address you gave to the address we got. So this needs to be very accurate for OAuth to work properly.

Comment: I do only use 1, just stating that i can use either, but the callback never gets hit, like in the Facebook Demo where the actionevent gets called and get the token that is returned, this does not happen when do the same thing through google

Comment: I suggest you file an issue in the issue tracker with sample code so we can actually run it in the debugger and see it. The issue tracker is here: http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same issue. I finally found out that the problem lies in the setup of the `WebBrowser` inside `Oauth2.createLoginComponent()`: the `onStart()` handler waits for a URL starting with your supplied redirect URI, but this URL never appears. The final Google page, the one that brings the token, has a URL starting with `"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?"`, not with the redirect URI.

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi) the token will be supplied inside the page title, but this appears not to be the case with the native browser in CodeName One. I therefore ended up scraping the HTML document for an `input` with `id="code"`, whose value is the token we're looking for. The scraping has to take place after the page has been loaded, i.e. in the `onLoad()` event, not in `onStart()`.

Hope this helps, it worked for me.